# Changing the Color of a dataset of two graphs in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, colors

im really new to Python and struggling with a task right now.
Basically i have a Dataset containing two subsets of data.
I have to plot this data in matplotlib, which i did.
But now i have to change the colors of the two graphs (they have to be different)
I tried plt.plot("dataset", color=['red', 'blue']); which results in an error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome :) A piece of the code you tried would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter([1,2,3],[4,5,6],color=['red','green','blue'])
```